# Storing one float value in vec3

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm working with 2D shadows in LWJGL and i'm storing distances in shadowmap in 3 color pixels (GL_RGB16), however i only use the 16-bit R channel and the other ones are left unused, which leads to bad shadow quality due to loss in float precision. So i'm looking for a way to store a float into one vec3 in glsl without precision loss (and unpacking it).

Comment: Why not use a format that has higher precision, like `GL_R32F`? That will use less space, and give you full float precision.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, realistically, you could either use a higher precision format (which would probably be much better since you would pass one uniform instead of three) or you could use a multiplication format to store your higher precision number.

For example, you could have the integer part of the number in the R (X) component, a floating point part in the G (Y) component and an additional multiplier in the B (Z) component. in the shader, to get the value out you would do the following operation:

```
float distance = (shadow.r + shadow.g) * shadow.b;
```

Now, I strongly discourage you use this system for a few reasons. Firstly, its computationally expensive to have to store a high precision value into this format and then to take it from this format back to the original value, especially considering you would be doing this very often (especially if you do the calculation in the fragment shader). Secondly, this is just a proof of concept, as I stated above, it would be a better idea to use a higher precision type, and send a single float uniform instead of a three component vector.